# I want to replace the inner text of HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed social bar in the left side of the single post, I want to change the text of a social button "fb Share", I tried it in many ways but no luck. Here is the [link](http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/title-for-post-2-will-go-here/) for checking the problem. I tried the following code:

`$('.pw-button-facebook').contents().find('span.pw-button-type-looknative__txt').text('New text');`

```
$('span.pw-button-type-looknative__txt:contains("Share")').html(function(i,h){
return h.replace('Share', 'New text');
});
```

`$('.pw-button-facebook').contents().find('span.pw-button-type-looknative__txt').html('New text');`

```
$('.pw-button-facebook span.pw-button-type-looknative__txt').contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function() {
this.data = this.data.replace(/Share/, 'New text'); 
});
```

So if you can please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a button generated by facebook you can't change it.

Comment: I think may be not. Can you please check the link ?

Comment: So, just sticking `$('.pw-button-type-looknative__txt').text('stuff')` in the console works just fine, so you either calling it to early and the buttons haven't loaded, or your doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.pw-button.pw-button-facebook').find('.pw-button-type-looknative__txt').text('Test');
```

Try this for facebook button.

Comment: I have placed it but I don't see any change here.

Comment: "jQuery.vegas is not a function" and " jQuery(...).fitVids is not a function" this is your errors in console, fix them and your script should works correct.

Comment: I also noticed this but I am using my jquery code correctly, this may be coming from plugin

Comment: If this errors appears earlier than your code - it wouldn't work. Before this line insert alert(1); and check it. Also check your code for been executing on document ready.

Comment: I used exactly like the following, so I think there is nothing wrong.

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pw-button-facebook .pw-button-type-looknative__txt').html('New word');
});
</script>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43574/discussion-between-pushok-and-joy-s)

Answer (score 1):

errrr

```
$('.pw-button-facebook .pw-button-type-looknative__txt').html('cat')
```

Works for me...

Comment: Per others comments, try adding a debugger to your code before the call. If you have a JS console open this will pause your browser and you can expect the environment (just like a debugger in Java etc..). Then you can diagnose if it is a timing bug or a syntax error :)